# Hourly collection of files across network

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, timer, threadpool

I'm currently working on an application in C# that will allow a user to select one or more networked drives or computers and collect Data Logs from a certain folder (folder location is always the same on any drive/PC) The files must be collected hourly, so at 10AM the application would collect the Data Logs of 9AM from each designated folder..

I'd like this to occur in a separate thread automatically on the hour, every hour for as long as the application is running in the background. The issue I have is that I am not familiar with how to set up this timer/hourly system so a thread can be made and run hourly. If anyone has any advise or ways I could perform this please let me know.

*I'm looking for options to be coded into this, as it will be distributed to 40 or 50 different PCs

Comment: [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) perhaps

Comment: It's probably best to have the program perform a one time action and then schedule it to run hourly in windows task scheduler, that way it's not sitting around doing nothing (while consuming system resources) during the rest of the hour.

Comment: @Servy could you go into abit more detail about this option?

Comment: @DarthSheldon What more detail do you need.  Don't have the job run forever, have it do one hour's worth of work and quit.  Use Windows, rather than C# code, to run it every hour.  Google can tell you how to use Task Scheduler if you've never used it before, it's a mostly intuitive application.

Comment: @Servy OK, that's not going to be a viable option for me. this application is going to be distributed to around 40 or so computers, having to manually set up some Task Scheduler on each isn't plausible. I'm looking for solutions in the C# code

Comment: @DarthSheldon: There's no need to manually set up a task with Task Scheduler. Have your application's install program run the [schtasks.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx) program to create the task. See [Programs are not cats](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/02/01/programs-are-not-cats/).

Comment: @Servy yeah I see your point. I think I will be going with a service though as I'm fairly unfamiliar with Task Scheduler and I don't know if it allows me to do several of my program's other features.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Windows Task Scheduler to invoke your program. It will make sure that you don't miss invocations, that your code is invoked at the right time and that you can easily deploy the next version of the tool using xcopy.

I think it can even retry failed jobs, send error reports and such.

You can script the task using a .bat-file or create it using C#. It is mass-deployable.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a windows service plus timer, have the service kick off at the start-up of your program. Let the service do all the 'heavy-lifting' and use a timer within the service. This will allow the destruction of GUI and release of it's held assets when not being used, as it's less obtrusive and resource heavy then an application hidden in the background.